# WooCommerce filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've updated WooCommerce to the latest 3.3 version. Everything went well, except I have one little issue and I can't seem to solve it.

At the checkout page, I created several custom input fields. Also I changed the label of some field. All modification is done in functions.php.

Oke, I have a field (billing_address_1) and changed the label of that field so it is called "straat" (dutch for street).
This was working in WooCommerce 3.0.0, but not in 3.3.

Here's my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 
'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
 $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = '';
    if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'nl' ): {
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Adres';
    }
    elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de' ): {
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Straßenname';
    }
    elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr' ): {
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Adresse';
    }
    elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' ): {
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Address';
    }
    elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es' ): {
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Dirección';
    }
    endif;
 return $fields;
}
```

For a long I can see, this filter hasn't changed in Woo 3.3 or am I missing something?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/), you'll see that you need to use the filter **woocommerce_default_address_fields** for altering some specific fields.

*In specific cases you need to use the woocommerce_default_address_fields filter. This filter is applied to all billing and shipping default fields:
country, first_name
, last_name
, company
, address_1
, address_2
, city
, state
, postcode*

Comment: Thanks. Haven't noticed that section in the docs. Solved my problem!

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit it but I fell for this one also ;)  Then I found the documentation and it all made sense.

Comment: Pfieeuw. Luckily i'm not the only one ;-)